# How to estimate coefficient of system of ODE with Matlab

Tags: matlab

would like to find coefficient of system below which has variable x

```
dS/dt = a1*S+a2*D+a3*F+a10*x
dD/dt = a4*S+a5*D+a6*F+a11*x
dF/dt = a7*S+a8*D+a9*F+a12*x
```

then i try without variable x, got error

```
dS/dt = a1*S+a2*D+a3*F
dD/dt = a4*S+a5*D+a6*F
dF/dt = a7*S+a8*D+a9*F

function getDE
    % find  
    [A, fval] = fminsearch(@objFcn, 10*randn(3));
end

function objVal = objFcn(A)

    % time span to be integrated over
    tspan = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27];

    % your desired data
    x11 = [0.208408965651696e-3 -0.157194487523421e-2 -0.294739401402979e-2 0.788206708183853e-2 0.499394753201753e-2 0.191468321959759e-3 0.504980449104750e-2 0.222150494088535e-2 0.132091821964287e-2 0.161118434883258e-2 -0.281236534046873e-2 -0.398055875132037e-2 -0.111753680372819e-1 0.588868146012489e-2 -0.354191562612469e-2 0.984082837373291e-3 -0.116041186868374e-1 0.603027845850267e-3 -0.448778128168742e-2 -0.127561485214862e-1 -0.412027655195339e-2 0.379387381798949e-2 -0.602550446997765e-2 -0.605986284736216e-2 -0.751396992404410e-2 0.633613424008655e-2 -0.677581832613623e-2];
    y11 = [ -21321.9719565717 231.709204951251 1527.92905167191 -32.8508507060675 54.9408176234139 -99.4222178124229 -675.771433486265 42.0838668074923 -12559.3183308951 5.21412214166344*10^5 1110.50031772203 3.67149699000155 -108.543878970269 -8.48861069398811 -521.810552387313 26.4792411876883 -8.32240296737599 -1085.40982521906 -44.1390030597906 -203.891397612798 -56.3746416571417 -218.205643256096 -178.991498697065 -42.2468018350386 .328546922634921 -1883.18308996621 111.747881085748];
    z11 = [ 1549.88755331800 -329.861725802688 8.54200301129155 -283.381775745327 -54.5469129127573 1875.94875597129 -16.2230517860850 6084.82381954832 1146.15489803104 -456.460512914647 104.533252701641 16.3998365630734 11.5710907832054 -175.370276462696 33.8045539958636 2029.50029336951 1387.92643570857 9.54717543291120 -1999.09590358328 29.7628085078953 2.58210333216737*10^6 57.7969622731082 -6.42551196941394 -8549.23677077892 -49.0081775323244 -72.5156360537114 183.539911458475];

    y_desired = [x11; y11; z11].';

    % solve the ODE
    y0 =  y_desired(1,:);
    [~,y_real] = ode45(@(~,y) A*y, tspan, y0);

    % objective function value: sum of squared quotients
    objVal = sum((1 - y_real(:)./y_desired(:)).^2);

end
```

error

```
>> getDE
??? Error: File: objFcn.m Line: 15 Column: 7
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Error in ==> fminsearch at 205
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Error in ==> getDE at 3
    [A, fval] = fminsearch(@objFcn, 10*randn(3));
```

Comment: Had a look and can not reproduce your error. I used `o = optimset('MaxIter',5,'MaxFunEvals',10)` - since it takes forever to evaluate. And `[A, fval] = fminsearch(@objFcn, 10*randn(3),o);` evaluates without errors. On Matlab 2012b. btw. this is an awfully complicated approach to solve this relatively simple equation system.-

Answer (score 0):

You seem you be using new code on an old MATLAB.

The older version does not yet support the tilde suppression notation (i.e., using `~` to suppress output arguments from a function).  It was introduced in R2009b (or round about there), and the notation is not backwards compatible.

Try

```
[ans,y_real] = ode45(@(t,y) A*y, tspan, y0);
```

or, if you insist

```
[DUMMY_, y_real] = ode45(@(t,y) A*y, tspan, y0);
clear DUMMY_
```

Comment: when trying it, it is busy, running a very long time, how to edit this program after introduce variable x when there is no data about x, must it a need to have data for x?